# Haskell: Variable not in scope?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to run the following code to get subsets of k-elements but getting `variable not in scope:ksubsets` Not exactly sure whY?

Code:

```
subsets :: [a] -> [[a]]
subsets [] = [[]]
subsets (x:xs) = [zs | ys <- subsets xs, zs <- [ys, (x:ys)]]


ksubsets k xs = [ys | ys<-subsets xs, length ys==k]
```

Comment: Exactly how do you run this?

Comment: ```:r``` then use ```ksubsets 3 [1,2,3,4,5]``` @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: and you did use a file to specify these functions? Or did you load these in `ghci` itself, since an `:r` will indeed clean the memory, and thus remove the ones not in the file.

Comment: used a file and ran it through ghci @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: can't reproduce. the code is working as is.

Comment: @WillNess is it possible to provide steps on how you ran it? I'm not sure where the issue is tbh

Comment: `ghci> :{`, then copy-paste your lines, then `ghci> :}`. (that's multi-line input mode)

Comment: @WillNess That worked. But why is it not loading from file?

Comment: you probably have some mix-up. carefully create new file, and load it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments, and possible problems and solutions:

1. There are no errors in your code, you can even try it online [here](https://repl.it/repls/UnsungKnownDistributeddatabase)
2. If you are using a text editor, check if you save your changes.
3. run ghci, and load your file

   $> ghci

   Prelude> :l path/to/your/file.hs
4. It should compile fine.

Comment: Thank you for the summary! Another problem i don't know how to solve, how would i filter subsets based on length of k elements? AGain, Thanks!